# Hierarchical Clustering Validation Statistics using FactoMineR

Tags: machine-learning, hierarchical-clustering

I'm running the HCPC function in the FactoMineR R package to perform hierarchical clustering on FAMD. I was able to run the HCPC function to generate clusters without any difficulty, but I was having difficulty running cluster.stats (from fpc package) to determine how well fitting my clusters were.

I understand that cluster.stats requires a distance matrix, but I'm unclear how to generate that from my HCPC command, below:

res.hcpc<-HCPC(res.famd, nb.clust = 4, method="ward", metric="euclidean")

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Raj